# Synchronize with the correct time

Tags: 7

This may not be Drupal specific, but does Drupal have a module that can fetch the correct world time from any remote time server, which can help me in keeping the time shown in my Drupal site correct?

I don't want to use my system time which may be inaccurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time is a server job, so you should ensure your system time is correct rather than try to solve this with Drupal.
I'd recommend you to set up a [NTP (Network Time Protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) client on your server and have it synchronizes with a NTP server.
Here is the documentation for Ubuntu: [Time Synchronisation with NTP](http://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/NTP.html).

PS: I think this question is off topic too ;)

Comment: Where are NTP servers? I mean which places are those located? Can't I use some php code to get latest time directly from those servers?

Comment: There's a lot of public NTP server, the tutorial for Ubuntu has one, here is a list of [public NTP servers](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/WebHome). Doing this in php is [feasible](http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/php/ntp_time_synchronization/index.php) but cumbersome because after you retrieve the date, then what ? Drupal still relies on system time, so it's way easier to get your system time correct in the first place.

Comment: If I get the time from my shared hosting server which seems to have correct time sync with NTP, and convert it to any part in the world, will it correctly translate with respect to DST etc?

Comment: Drupal is the one who managed the Time Zones translation, so this should works flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on shared hosting your hosting company should be responsible for keeping the time correct. If that's not happening contact them and ask why. If you are on VPS or your own private server you can set up a NTP client as tostinni recommended.